# How to make <table> column right-aligned

Tags: html, html-table

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col style='text-align:right'>
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sample text</td>
      <td>This text should be right-aligned</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <div id='spacer' style='width:100px'>
          I'm a spacer
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Results in text that isn't right aligned. If the same style is applied to the `td` element it works fine. How do I right-align text in a column without having to apply a style to every `td` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
table.tableClass tr td:nth-child(2) {
   text-align: right;
}
```

the number after `nth-child(` is the column, so for this case it would be 2 because it's the second column. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p97vdo2p/1/

Comment: Relevant: @Shel, if you look at the [MDN docs for `<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col#Attributes), you find this: "Do not try to set the text-align property on a selector giving a `<col>` element. Because `<td>` elements are not descendant of the `<col>` element, they won't inherit it."

Comment: @misterManSam I looked over the MDN docs many times over and somehow missed/didn't comprehend that.

Answer (score 1):

HTML isn't rendered by column, it's rendered by rows. That's why there `<tr></tr>` (table rows) exist, but `<tc></tc>` (table columns) do not. That being said, the easiest way to style a column in HTML, is by applying the same CSS class to every `<td></td>` in the given column. You can type in the same class to every one manually, or you could write it programmatically, via javascript or a server-side script.